# "Begin" + infinitive: in the past (perhaps) there has been some activity

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

> In the first meaning of **begin**, it is possible to use the -ing form
> or the to + verb (infinitive) form after it:
>
> *She stood up and **began** playing* or *to play the trumpet*.
>
> With the -ing form we expect the trumpet playing to go on for a while,
> and assume that **in the past (perhaps) there has been some playing**.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/begin

How is it possible for there to be some playing in the past when it has just **began** ? Perhaps she began to play again after recovering from some injury?

Can't you say *She **began to** play **again***?

Comment: Gerund-participle clauses and infinitive clauses are untensed— don't be misled by _ing_ constructions everytime you see them. They don't always show tense.

Comment: They don't ever show tense, _-ing_ verb forms are not inflected for tense. There are only two tenses in English - past and present. Everything else is constructions with auxiliary verbs, and there are hundreds of them and they're not tenses. No wonder you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible for there to be some playing in the past when it has just began?

I think it's possible if you use 'begin' to mean 'resume', although I don't agree with this kind of hair-splitting.

Comment: Perhaps she began to play again after recovering from some injury